# Django i18n blocktrans vs trans

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

In Django templates, what exactly is the difference between these two:

```
{% blocktrans %}My Text{% endblocktrans %}

{% trans 'My Text' %}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code)

**Trans template tag**

> The {% trans %} template tag translates either a constant string (enclosed in single or >double quotes) or variable content:

With a Trans tag, you are limited to a single constant string or variable. So you would have to use

```
{# These Would Work! #}
title>{% trans "This is the title." %}</title>
<title>{% trans myvar %}</title>
```

But could not use

```
{%trans "This is my title {{ myvar }}" %}
```

**Blocktrans template tag**

> Contrarily to the trans tag, the blocktrans tag allows you to mark complex sentences 
>   consisting of literals and variable content for translation by making use of placeholders:

With a Blocktrans, this kind of code is possible:

```
    {% blocktrans with book_t=book|title author_t=author|title %}
       This is {{ book_t }} by {{ author_t }}
    {% endblocktrans %}
```

So Blocktrans is going to allow you to be a bit more complex and through in your output.

But to answer your question literally: not much. Except for the presentation style, both will be sent to the translator as the string `'My Text'`

Comment: Perfect. I think the catch for me was in how variables are handled in the tags. I didn't realize the trans tag couldn't mix variables and strings. Thanks!

Comment: any downside to using blocktrans for both?

Comment: Nope. It is purely a matter of preference.